# python converting a List of Tuples into a Dict with external keys

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuples like this

```
[
(1,'a'),
(2,'b'),
(3,'c'),
(4,'d'),
(5,'e')
]
```

The result should be a list of dictionaries

```
[
{'id': 1, 'label': 'a'},
{'id': 2, 'label': 'b'},
{'id': 3, 'label': 'c'},
{'id': 4, 'label': 'd'},
{'id': 5, 'label': 'e'}
]
```

I'm using python 3.6 
The first value in every tuple is named as 'id' and the second value 
in every tuple is named as 'label'.
I want to get the above result without using loop since the data will be huge.
Is there any built-in method to achieve my result?

Answer (score 3):

Using `map`

**Ex:**

```
data = [
(1,'a'),
(2,'b'),
(3,'c'),
(4,'d'),
(5,'e')
]

keys = ["id", 'label']    
print(list(map(lambda x: dict(zip(keys, x)), data)))

#List comprehension 
#print([dict(zip(keys, i)) for i in data])
```

**Output:**

```
[{'id': 1, 'label': 'a'},
 {'id': 2, 'label': 'b'},
 {'id': 3, 'label': 'c'},
 {'id': 4, 'label': 'd'},
 {'id': 5, 'label': 'e'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple comprehension will do:

```
l = [
(1,'a'),
(2,'b'),
(3,'c'),
(4,'d'),
(5,'e')
]
results = [{"id" : id, "label": label} for id, label in l]
```

If your data is too big you can use a generator (so it will be lazily evaluated):

```
    results = ({"id" : id, "label": label} for id, label in l)
```

Or use `map`:

```
    results = map(lambda x: {"id" : x[0], "label": x[1]}, l)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools as it     # pip install itertools 
ids=[]   # lists
a=[
(1,'a'),        # input
(2,'b'),
(3,'c'),
(4,'d'),
(5,'e')
]
for i, j in a :
#    for j in i:
    di=("id", i ,"label", j)
    ids.append(dict(it.zip_longest(*[iter(di)] * 2, fillvalue="")))
print(ids)
```

```
output :

[{'id': 5, 'label': 'e'}, {'id': 5, 'label': 'e'}, {'id': 5, 'label': 'e'}, {'id': 5, 'label': 'e'}, {'id': 5, 'label': 'e'}]
```